# LiveSDK 5.6.3 not working in UWP store app

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp, live-sdk

I have a universal windows store app targeting Windows 10. In a previous version of the app targeting Windows 8.1 I used the LiveSDK ([the 5.6 version here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42552)) to access data from the user's MS Live account using the `LiveAuthClient`. In the new version of the app, I figured I'd use the most recent version of the LiveSDK ([5.6.3 available as a nuget package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveSDK)) but when I install the nuget package, I am unable to to access the Microsoft.Live namespace.

For example, the following statement:

```
using Microsoft.Live;
```

Produces the error `"The type or namespace 'Live' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'"`

Is this package broken or am I missing something obvious here? I would have expected this to work just like it did with the 5.6 version of the LiveSDK. It also seems like the [documentation for the LiveSDK](https://dev.onedrive.com/) is all pointing to info about the OneDrive api now so it makes me wonder if the purpose of the sdk has changed. I'm confused... What's the most recent version of the LiveSDK (the one that has the `LiveAuthClient`) and where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why *Nuget Manager* doesn't add a reference automatically, but it seems to work once you add a reference manually from directory:

`C:\Users\USER\.nuget\packages\LiveSDK\5.6.3\WindowsXAML\MicrosoftLive.dll`.

[image]

Comment: Better still; copy that *Microsoft.Live.dll* file into the following folder and then un-install and then re-install the package

C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\LiveSDK\5.6.3\lib\netcore45  (Forces NuGet to do some of the work)