# Live SDK assembly reference missing when developing Universal App on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, live-sdk

I am developing an app using windows 10 SDK and I want to use Live SDK. I am using VS 2015 and I have installed Live SDK through nuget.

Following code has been taken from MSDN sample code:

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient;
    private async Task<int> UploadFileToOneDrive()
    {
        try
        {
            //  create OneDrive auth client
            var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();

            //  ask for both read and write access to the OneDrive
            LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });

            //  if login successful 
            if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                //  create a OneDrive client
                liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);

                //  create a local file
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                //  copy some txt to local file
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, "Hello OneDrive World!!");

                using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await ms.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
                }

                //  create a folder
                string folderID = await GetFolderID("folderone");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderID))
                {
                    //  return error
                    return 0;
                }

                //  upload local file to OneDrive
                await liveClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(folderID, file.Name, file, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

                return 1;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        //  return error
        return 0;
    }

    public async Task<int> DownloadFileFromOneDrive()
    {
        try
        {
            string fileID = string.Empty;

            //  get folder ID
            string folderID = await GetFolderID("folderone");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderID))
            {
                return 0; // doesnt exists
            }

            //  get list of files in this folder
            LiveOperationResult loResults = await liveClient.GetAsync(folderID + "/files");
            List<object> folder = loResults.Result["data"] as List<object>;

            //  search for our file 
            foreach (object fileDetails in folder)
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> file = fileDetails as IDictionary<string, object>;
                if (string.Compare(file["name"].ToString(), "filename", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    //  found our file
                    fileID = file["id"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileID))
            {
                //  file doesnt exists
                return 0;
            }

            //  create local file
            StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename_from_onedrive", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            //  download file from OneDrive
            await liveClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync(fileID + "/content", localFile);

            return 1;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Problem is that even after installing nuget, LiveConnectClient is not getting recognised. Its assembly reference is missing. When I tried setting it manually by adding the reference, it is still not getting resolved. (Could it be meant only for windows 8?)

The Live SDK information is shown in the image below:

[image]

The Live SDK is from here: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check if the reference has been properly added, [if not, add it manually](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33215523/2681948).

Comment: added image reference of Live SDK

Comment: @Romasz: after manually adding link to Microsoft.Live.dll, resolved the problem. Thank you. But it is still confusing why VS didn't recognize auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a *Nuget package* problem, hence [adding a reference manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33215523/2681948) seems to resolve the issue. You will find the reference in:

`C:\Users\USER\.nuget\packages\LiveSDK\5.6.3\WindowsXAML\MicrosoftLive.dll`